# How to Bulk insert with a dynamic value for a column

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

the situation is this:

I have 200 txt files with different names like **601776.txt** each file's name is actually an ID_foo and it contains some data like this (2 columns):

```
04004 Albánchez
04006 Albox
04008 Alcóntar
04009 Alcudia de Monteagud
.
.
.
```

now I wanna **BULK INSERT** these TXT files into a SQL Server Table which has 3 column one of these columns should be the name of the txt file. I'm using a PHP script, so I made a loop to get the file names and then what?

```
BULK INSERT Employee_Table
    FROM '../home/601776.txt'  
    WITH (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t',  
         ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' 
        )
```

how can i set the third column while bulk inserting with $file_name variable in each loop?

Do you think it is a better idea if it is possible to insert the table by reading the txt file line by line? And how?

Thanks

Comment: When I have done stuff like this in C#, I have written a method to go into the file and add the data I need into the CSV. The Bulk_Insert (as far as I am aware, please correct me if I am wrong) is pretty dumb, in that it just picks up the file and inserts, you can't really interfere. So, to save hassle, I get the file how I need it before bulk insert.

Comment: @Leonidas199x that's an good option too but i want to know is there a way to use directly BULK INSERT

Comment: so you want to have a 3rd column with the file name and do the bulk insert on `n` number of files... basically all of them in a directory i suspect?

Comment: @scsimon exactly

Comment: @scsimon i'm not an expert in database scripts so i made a php script to change the text file and add the name of file at the end of each lines then i bulk inserted to the database and problem solved. Thank you by the way but it would be great if you explain how to use your script and describe it more

Comment: @AriaR. all you have to do is set the fileLocation (which is the directory) and run it... it will grab every file in that directory and insert it into the table Employee_Table with the file name and load date. You only have to run it once and bam, it's done.

Comment: @scsimon it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the few times that a cursor is actually ideal in SQL Server. Here's a way. Once you see the PRINT statement and are satisfied you can comment it out and uncomment out the two lines below it. I put some logic in to add the file name and a processed date which is usually needed, but your table definition would need these columns. It should get the idea across.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Set some variables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(10)                                                         --date variable but stored as VARCHAR for formatting of file name
DECLARE @fileLocation VARCHAR(128) = 'E:\DATA_TRANSFERS\'                       --production location which is \\issqlstd01 but the xp_dirtree didn't like this
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)                                                     --dynamic sql variable
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(128)                                                  --full file name variable


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Get a list of all the file names in the directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    ,depth int
    ,isfile bit)
INSERT #FileNames (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @fileLocation, 1, 1





---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Create a cursor to fetch the file names
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
select subdirectory from #FileNames where isfile = 1

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @fileName

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--For each file, bulk insert 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT Employee_Table FROM '''+ @fileLocation + @fileName +''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',KEEPNULLS,ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'')'


        --Try the bulk insert, if error is thrown log the error 
        --Also update the Table Columns which aren't a part of the original file (load date and original file name)
        BEGIN TRY
            PRINT(@sql)
            --EXEC(@sql)
            --UPDATE Employee_Table SET OrigFile = @fileName, LoadDate = GETDATE() WHERE OrigFile IS NULL
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @fileName
    END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

GO
```