# SQL Server 2016 - Import data with file ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, import

I have 5 files with the same structure that I'd like to import to SQL Server 2016 with a new column to identify which file they came from.

File 1

```
RowID   GroupID   ItemID
  1        234     45642
  2        234     23485
  3        234     42322
```

File 2

```
RowID   GroupID   ItemID
  1        234     45642
  2        234     23485
  3        234     42322
```

New Table:

```
RowID   GroupID   ItemID   FileID
  1        234     45642    File_1
  2        234     23485    File_1
  3        234     42322    File_1
  1        234     45642    File_2
  2        234     23485    File_2
  3        234     42322    File_2
```

Is there a way to do this in the import wizard or do I have to write a BULK COPY statement or something else?

Comment: I answered a similar question for a list of files in a directory here that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440114/how-to-bulk-insert-with-a-dynamic-value-for-a-column/44447617#44447617. If you import then one at a time you could run an update on the table in a similar fashion.