# Script to import text files to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import

I have around 1000 text files that need to be imported as tables to MS SQL Server. Usually I use Import and Export Data Tool, but doing that a 1000 times would be insufficient.
Is there a way to automate the process and import the 1000 text files and create the tables in SQL without doing that manually? Can that be achieved using a script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44447617/6167855

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS. Start with your export package saved to the file system. In SSDT create a new SSIS project. Delete the Package.dtsx file created with the project. Right click the Packages "folder" and select Add Existing Package, navigate to the package you saved and select it. Now you can start automating the loads.